# Copying table records after a specific file interval in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table whose records I want to copy to a db on a remote server after a specific interval of time. The number of records in the table is very high(in the range of millions) and also the columns can range from 40-50.

I thought about using pg_dump after the time-interval but that sounds inefficient as the whole table would be dumped again and again.

Assume the time interval to be 4 hours and the life-cycle of db start at 10:00.

No. of Records at 10:00 - 0

No. of Records at 14:00 - n

No. of Records at 18:00 - n+m

No. of Records at 22:00 - n+m+l

The script(shell) that I want to write should select 0 rows at 10:00,
n rows at 14:00, m rows at 18:00, l rows at 22:00.

Is there any other way through which I copy only those rows that have been added between the time intervals in order to remove the redundant rows that will come if I take a pg_dump every 4 hours?

Comment: Would help if you had an id / timestamp field to store somewhere so you only selected data higher than that id / timestamp. You can easily add a BIGSERIAL to the table. If you're after shifting data fast, go look up pgloader - great tool. I'm shipping 50M+ rows out of an S3 bucket into my RDS in under 10 minutes, including ETL

Comment: @NickPfitzner Can you elaborate on the solution that you are using. I do have id as well as timestamp field present.

Comment: If you export at a certain time, put the MIN and MAX values of id (or timestamp) into a table somewhere. Then, next time you run your export, you SELECT WHERE id > (previous MAX) into a table. pg_dump that table and then use that data to update.